# using R dplyr replace NA with group mean but omitting some values from group before mean calculation

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, na

This seems like it should be a simple one but I can't see it.

Say I have a dataframe like:

```
df <- data.frame(type=c(rep("A", 5), rep("B",5)),
                 stage=rep(c("1","2", "3", "4", "5"),2),
                 val=c(rnorm(n=5, mean=1000, sd=300),rnorm(n=4, mean=1000, sd=100), NA)
                 )
```

I want to be able to replace the NA in group `type=="B"` by the mean of group B, but omit some "vals" from B (e.g. where "stage" equals 1 OR stage equals 2 - or any other condition). Using `dplyr`and `zoo` its easy to fill in with the group mean:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(type) %>% dplyr::mutate_at("val", zoo::na.aggregate)
```

but I can't work out how to exclude vals from the group based on condition in "stage". Ideally, a dplyr solution but including zoo would also be good.

Comment: Sorry should add I want all values to remain in the df, only the NA replaced

Comment: You could split the dataset and them union both parts, the question is what happens when there are missing variables in the part that you aren't using to calculate the mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it with the condition `stage != 2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(type=c(rep("A", 5), rep("B",5)),
                 stage=rep(c("1","2", "3", "4", "5"),2),
                 val=c(rnorm(n=5, mean=1000, sd=300),rnorm(n=4, mean=1000, sd=100), NA)
)



df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(val = replace_na(val, mean(val[stage != 2], na.rm = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   type [2]
#>    type  stage   val
#>    <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#>  1 A     1     1176.
#>  2 A     2     1213.
#>  3 A     3      967.
#>  4 A     4      864.
#>  5 A     5     1182.
#>  6 B     1      818.
#>  7 B     2     1063.
#>  8 B     3      972.
#>  9 B     4      972.
#> 10 B     5      921.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I set the seed to a number so everybody gets the same numbers.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was after - couldn't work out where to put the subset bits.